# Pattern rule seems to be ignored

Tags: makefile

Here is my Makefile, I am trying to use Make to concatenate / minify my JS scripts:

```
all: myproject.js

JS_TARGETS = file1.js file2.js
JS_MINIFIED = $(JS_TARGETS:.js=.min.js)

# I use addprefix because my files are in a js/ directory
myproject.js: $(addprefix js/, $(JS_MINIFIED)) $(addprefix js/, $(JS_TARGETS))
    cat $^ >$@

# Minification + new line
%.min.js: %.js
    uglifyjs -o $< $@
    echo >> $<

clean:
    rm -f myproject.js

.PHONY: clean
```

Answer (score 1):

Mmm sorry, it was a `$@` / `$<` confusion, it works now:

```
# Minification + new line
%.min.js: %.js
    uglifyjs -o $@ $<
    echo >> $@
```